# How to continue the process of component after routing back in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm struggling with the problem mentioned in the title... In application, which I'm writing, at the beginning of the flow, user lands on `/process` page, where one REST service is called multiple times with different input based on previous response. During this process some data are presented on the screen. If something goes wrong with one of the calls, user is redirected to `/resolve` page where he needs to take some actions. After that, by clicking 'Retry' button, he can go back to `/process` page in state, which left and continue the process. By continue the process, I mean that application will continue its flow by finishing the calls in the loop and refreshing the view with new data for each iteration.

In order to navigate between the routes, I'm using: `Router.nagivate(['/expectedPath'])`. To go back to page in state, which has been left, I decided to use `RouteReuseStrategy`. And it's working like a charm.

But now I'm wondering how to continue 'paused' flow on `/process` page. Was it a good choice to go with `Router` and `RouteReuseStrategy` or should I achieve it different way? At the beginning it seemed like a reasonable way, but now I'm not sure and that's why I decided to ask for help. I'm using Angular 8.

Comment: You can store the status of this "process" in a shared service. When you enter the /process page, check this status and proceed accordinaly.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler so it wasn't the correct way, which I've chose and I should replace this `RouteReuseStrategy` with this `shared service`?? Is it even approachable this way? Going back to your suggestion, basically `/process' component will be recreated from scratch every time, but based on condition in `ngOnInit()` it will get state from service and continue the flow or start flow from the begining (first landing on the page). Correct?